# They have taken everything out of the cupboards and THREW it on the floor (?)

Tags: difference, past-tense, present-perfect

> George and Joan LIVE (live) in a small house in London. Right now they ARE STANDING (stand) in the sitting room of their house. They HAVE JUST COME (just come) back from a holiday in the country . They ARRIVED ( arrive) at the house five minutes ago.
>
> "What HAS HAPPENED (happen)?" said Joan, as she LOOKED (look) round at the untidy room. "Someone HAS BEEN (be) in the house. They HAVE TAKEN (take) everything out of the cupboards and **THREW** (throw) it on the floor.  Look, George, they HAVE BROKEN (break) all those glasse

Why is it "threw" instead of "thrown"; why was the past simple used instead of present perfect, I think it would be logical to be present perfect, she is discovering what happened it is more present than past.

http://www.english-grammar.at/online_exercises/tenses/all_tenses3.htm
This comes from   T026-Back from the holidays - All Tenses

Comment: I agree with you - *they have thrown it on the floor* would be better here.

Comment: The question should be closed because it's based on wrong answers to the given test. See @Mari-Lou's answer.

Comment: You need to read the answer key again. That's not what the correct answers are, according to the website.

Answer (score 1):

I did that online exercise and these were my answers

[image]

The answers for 1-4 are in the past simple tense

1. What _____ (happen)?  **happened**
2. Someone _______ (be) in the house.  **was**
3. They _________ (take) everything out. **took**
4. and ______ (throw) it on the floor **threw**

The text tells the reader that George and Joan **arrived** five minutes ago. Since the act of being robbed occurred BEFORE their arrival, the following tenses are in past simple. The last two gap fills (empty spaces) are in the imperative mood.